# Linq to Sql conversion giving null each time

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL query as:

```
 select * from EH_PP_TeacherObservations tos
 join account acc on tos.EH_PP_TeacherAcctId = acc.id
join EH_PP_ObserverStatus os on tos.EH_PP_TeacherAcctId = os.EH_PP_AcctId 
join [dbo].[EH_PP_TeacherObservationStatusesRefTable] tosrt on tos.[EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH] = tosrt.[EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusID]
where tos.[EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH] = 'A717732D-68FA-47FE-A354-C2CB589F29FA' and os.[EH_PP_O_isObserver]= 1
```

I want to convert it to LINQ.

I tried as below:

```
 list = (

                         from a in context.EH_PP_TeacherObservations
                         join b in context.accounts on a.EH_PP_TeacherAcctId equals b.id
                         join c in context.EH_PP_ObserverStatus on a.EH_PP_TeacherAcctId equals c.EH_PP_AcctId
                         join d in context.EH_PP_TeacherObservationStatusesRefTables on a.EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH equals d.EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusID
                         where a.EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH == new Guid("A717732D-68FA-47FE-A354-C2CB589F29FA")
                         && c.EH_PP_O_isObserver == true
                       select new Entity.Observations
                       {
                           FullName = (b.firstName + " " + b.lastName),
                           EH_PP_ObservationID = Guid.Parse(a.EH_PP_ObservationID.ToString()),
                           EH_PP_TE_TeacherEvalID = Guid.Parse(a.EH_PP_TE_TeacherEvalID.ToString()),
                           EH_PP_TOT_ObservationStartDateTime = a.EH_PP_TOT_ObservationStartDateTime,
                           EH_PP_TOT_ObservationEndDateTime = a.EH_PP_TOT_ObservationEndDateTime,
                           EH_PP_TOT_Announced = int.Parse(a.EH_PP_TOT_Announced.ToString()),
                           EH_PP_TOT_ObservationNum = a.EH_PP_TOT_ObservationNum.ToString(),
                           EH_PP_TeacherAcctId = a.EH_PP_TeacherAcctId.ToString(),
                           EH_PP_ObserverAcctID = Guid.Parse(a.EH_PP_ObserverAcctID.ToString()),
                           EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH = a.EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH.ToString()
                       }
                    ).ToList<Entity.Observations>();
```

But its showing me null.

Please help me.

Comment: What's showing you null?

Comment: And that is ok? Then add a null check before you call ToList. Otherwise remove joins and/or fields from your select projection until you get rows. We can't help you with that.

Comment: @rene  but sql result and linq results are different thats why i posted.. is there any mistake in Linq query formation???

Comment: Why don't you attach the sqlprofiler to see the sqlstatement that Linq produces for you and start your debugging there?

Comment: Start with removing the `where` does it return results in that case? If yes: add one clause from the where. If not, remove a table, continue until you have results and then add back the stuff you removed until it no longer works. The last thing you added is broken. To get that fixed you might consider asking on SO... in its current form it is a guess...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the where statement:
a.EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH is not equal new Guid("A717732D-68FA-47FE-A354-C2CB589F29FA")
try Convert.ToString(a.EH_PP_TOSRT_TeacherObservationStatusIDEH).ToUpper() = "A717732D-68FA-47FE-A354-C2CB589F29FA"

Note: Guid is struct, so comparing struct in C# is a pain, equals always return false if even your objects have the same value.